# Radzen DataGridColumn filter on Enum string representation

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, radzen

I have a Datagrid that use the string representation of an enum to display the data.
The filter on String or Date field works well, but not on this enum field.
[image: enum_row_capture]

```html
<RadzenDataGrid AllowFiltering="true"  FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple" PageSize="100" AllowPaging="true"
                AllowSorting="true"
                FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                Data="@dataList" TItem="TableName">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="TableName" Property="Status" Title="Status">
            <Template Context="dataItem">
                <TransactionStatus Status="@dataItem.Status"/>
            </Template>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="TableName" Property="myDate" Title="Date" />
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>
```

The value of Status is like 0, 1, 2...
How to filter by just typing the textuel representation of the enum value as displayed in the grid ?

Comment: @user13256346, Sorry, Yes it is working to display the value, but the multi selection doesn't work, but it is an other problem, thank you

Comment: Ok, it was due to the version of the component, after an update everything works fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try in your Data like this

`Data=@Enum.GetValues(typeof(yourClass))`